# How to get Resource Path on AWS API Gateway?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm working with a AWS API Gateway that receives a **{name}** as prints out "**Hello {name}**" but I'm unable to get this trivial task right.

Any pointers what I could be doing wrong? How the can I get the {name} from the URL?

**API Gateway:**
https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/John

**Python AWS Lamba code:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    name = event["requestContext"]["resourcePath"]
    response = "Hello " + name
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response
    }
```

**The expected output:**

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "Hello John"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [proper](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pass-api-gateway-rest-api-parameters/) mapping template on Gateway side. It cannot map whatever you want automatically, you need to configure what you expect there.